# Error when creating a singleton in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a singleton in typescript. Here's my code

```
export class AssetsController {
  
    private serviceConfig: ServiceConfig | undefined;
    private static _instance: AssetsController;

    constructor() {
        this.serviceConfig = undefined;
    }

    public static getInstance(): AssetsController {
        if (!AssetsController._instance) {
            AssetsController._instance = new AssetsController();
        }
        return AssetsController._instance;
    }
    public createFolder() {
      return true;
    }
}
```

// other file

```
var result = AssetsController.getInstance().createFolder(); // throws an error SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOA3AlgYwgYQPYDsBmyA5lALxQCuOA1jlgO44DcAUM6gDYCGAzt1AIK8IwbthzB4WduwRQA3syhRFSqGHjJEnYNG4IU6MQUIAuWPrSZcxqAB8KOACYQCOCI5aq1GrTqjdgbTQoAH1kHADOHHQzQT0RMQkpGXgWFSVUXAD4clRgLHgACgBKeXSvKGAAC2RuADo9JEsjIlIHZ1d3T1UAX1YvMHIAI3ZgyOBgwmEASQjA6IgS2KEE3CTpWQUK1WQ8KEKAQjjhUTXJDfg6sLmo9FKt7Yrj1fFzlKvwyIW2tzoBFdOr2SCBK3W2fUeUHgwnI8Bw-3igPW72uX3QYKgENUgxGwVQ0O0EAAYlJnEV7uUlNDgLD4RJyBAMX0+mwssAoRBuOR2OyyM8kW8EHUpsBZmjFsU6viIISSewyaDWREpBA6uwsIRCtCuTziiwgA)

When I call `AssetsController.getInstance().createFolder()` from another file, I get the error   `SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'`. After some debugging, I realized that it's because of how I initialize the singleton. Can someone please help?

Comment: I think you are mistaken about the cause and nature of the SyntaxError you're experiencing. I think your JS engine is trying to run a `.ts` file instead of a _transpiled_ `.js` file.

Comment: I updated the class to make more sense. The ts file is converted to a js file before the code is run. When I remove the getInstance() from the file, the file runs correctly. It's the getInstance that's a problem.

Comment: I updated the question. See above. @Dai

Comment: You're code doesn't actually have any syntax errors. This sounds like the javascript runtime is trying to execute a raw typescript file without compiling it first. So whatever the issue is probably doesn't have anything to do with the code you've posted. How are you compiling and running this app? How are you importing the files in question?

Comment: @ChrisHansen There was a typo on the `createFolder` method, so I removed it (and also added a link to your code in the TS Playground). I agree with Alex.